# prove with $\epsilon$-$\delta$-argument: $x\rightarrow |-2x+3|$ is continuous

Tags: limits, proof-writing, continuity, problem-solving

i am asked to prove with $\epsilon$-$\delta$-argument that $x\rightarrow |-2x+3|$ is continuous

my steps: 
Definition of $\epsilon-\delta$-argument:
$\forall \epsilon >0 \exists \delta>0$ with $|x-x_0|<\delta \Longrightarrow |f(x)-f(x_0)|<\epsilon$

so: $|f(x)-f(x_0)|=||-2x+3|-|-2x_0+3|| = |(2x+3)-(2x_0+3)| = |2x-2x_0|=\ldots\text{help}\ldots<\epsilon$

i am stuck there again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The step
$$\left|\left|-2x+3\right|-\left|-2x_0+3\right|\right| = \left|(2x+3)-(2x_0+3)\right| 
$$
is wrong (how did you get that?). We have
$$\left|f(x)-f(x_0)\right|=\left|\left|-2x+3\right|-\left|-2x_0+3\right|\right| \le \left|(-2x+3)-(-2x_0+3)\right| =2\left|x-x_0\right|
$$
by a variant of the triangle inequality
$$\left|\left|a\right|-\left|b\right|\right| \le \left|a-b\right| $$
We must have 
$$\left|f(x)-f(x_0)\right|<\epsilon$$
Because
$$\left|f(x)-f(x_0)\right|<2\left|x-x_0\right|$$
it suffices
$$\left|x-x_0\right|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$$
whenever
$$\left|x-x_0\right|<\delta$$
How will you choose your $\delta_{\epsilon}$?

Comment: @doniyor You mean $\delta=\frac{\epsilon}2$ right?

Comment: Yes so that the last two equations are the same

Comment: so, generally, $\delta$ and $\epsilon$ should stay equal? visually, they are the small areas in $x$ and $y$ planes, right?

Comment: @doniyor No. Here $\delta=\frac{\epsilon}2<\epsilon$